# Best pricing for Azure Storage+Cloud service+SQL Azure solution

Tags: azure

We are designing our solution and want to build it in azure. There are few components and we end up with the following workflow:

1. **WebRole1** -> store data to blob storage
2. **WorkerRole2** processes blobs and save the output into **Azure SQL Table1**
3. **WorkerRole3** processes data from **Azure SQL Table1** and stores the results in **Azure SQL Table2**
4. **Excel** is used to report upon the data in **Azure SQL Table2**

As far as I understand the pricing model we will need to pay for the outgoing traffic crossing datacenter boundary and here is the question. 
What is the cheapest locations structure for the above workflow?

We tried to create Cloud Service instances but there is no **West US** option for the datacenter, while we can have blob storage and SQL Database in **West US**. The closest option looks to be **Central US** for Cloud service, but that would mean we will pay for the traffic, which we prefer not to. Is there any chance we can have all 3 components in the same datacenter (blob storage, cloud service and sql database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (and should) create all of these components in the same data center. The four data centers in the United States are North Central US, South Central US, West US, and East US.

To create a new cloud service in the West US data center, log in to the Windows Azure management portal, choose Cloud Services, and click New. Select "West US" as the region.